# How to setup apache shark on Hadoop yarn?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have setup a spark cluster on hadoop yarn and now i want to setup shark on spark. 
but there are no article to setup shark on spark which is setup on yarn. 
Is there any way we can do that or should i move setup my spark cluster as stand alone cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one of the working model i have implemented

https://github.com/amplab/shark/wiki/Running-Shark-on-a-Cluster